# How to refer relative paths for code outside pom project?

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I have a very different situation to deal with. Something never seen before.

I have a codebase which is not a maven based project. It basically is set of `Pig` Script that are executed on `Hadoop` Cluster.

Now there is requirement to test these scripts using `PigUnit`, so I created a maven based project with all dependencies needed for the project.

Visually it looks like

```
user_mapper/
           src/main/
                   user.pig
                   other.pig
           test/
               pom.xml
               src/java/
                      /UserTest.java
                      /OtherTest.java
```

As you could see, `test` is a maven based project in itself.

**What I need**
In `UserTest.java` I want to refer to **relative path** of `user.pig`

How can I provide a relative path in `UserTest.java`?

Comment: What do you mean by "provide"? Is `../../../src/main/user.pig` not what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code (internally uses commons-io jar)

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class FileReader {

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FileReader.class.getName());

static String webAppPath;

private static final boolean IS_WINDOWS = System.getProperty( "os.name" ).contains( "indow" );

private InputStream inputStream;
private static FileReader fileReader;

public String getAbsolutePath(Class appClass, String relativePath) {
    try {
        String parentPath = "";
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(webAppPath)) {
            parentPath = webAppPath;
        } else {
            parentPath = appClass.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        }

        String osAppropriatePath = IS_WINDOWS ? parentPath.substring(1) : parentPath;

        String absolutePath = osAppropriatePath + relativePath;
        File file = new File(absolutePath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, IOUtils.toString(readFile(relativePath), "UTF-8"));
        }
        return absolutePath;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ioe);
        return relativePath;
    }
}



public void closeFileReader() {

    synchronized (this) {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FileReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}

private FileReader() {

}

public static FileReader getInstance() {

    return new FileReader();

}

public static String getWebAppPath() {
    return webAppPath;
}

public static void setWebAppPath(String webAppPath) {
    FileReader.webAppPath = webAppPath;
}

}
```

And call the class to get the relative path as follows

```
 FileReader.getInstance().getAbsolutePath(user.pig, "user.pig");
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using `java.io.File` as

```
final String filePath = new File("../src/user.pig").getAbsolutePath();
```